# How to restrict cpu usage while running docker containers in parallel using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Executing automation ui test cases inside docker container.
Using docker-compose for the same.
we have categorized the test cases into multiple modules and each module represents a service in docker-compose file. There are 40 services.

Here is the docker-compose file ( showing with 2 services):

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  Module1:
    image: ${Image_Name}    
    command: powershell "cd C:\tools;&'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe' /testcontainer:C:\tools\SpecFlowProject.dll /category:Module1 /resultsfile:C:\tools\Module1.trx /testsettings:C:\tools\TestSettings.testsettings"
    volumes:
      - ${Source_Path}:${Dest_Path}
  Module2:
    image: ${Image_Name}    
    command: powershell "cd C:\tools;&'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe' /testcontainer:C:\tools\SpecFlowProject.dll /category:Module2 /resultsfile:C:\tools\Module2.trx /testsettings:C:\tools\TestSettings.testsettings"
    volumes:
      - ${Source_Path}:${Dest_Path}
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

.env file is mentioned below:

```
Source_Path=C:\Automation
Dest_Path=C:\tools
Image_Name=automation/testagent:v63
Tagname=latest
```

The hardware configuration of host is 12 GB RAM with 12 CPU's.
When we execute the docker-compose, the cpu goes 100% continuously and we are getting the timeout error as well as unable to connect to remote server error while executing the test cases.
If we execute the docker-compose with 2 services at time, then there is no burden on cpu utilization, and all test cases passed.
The entire test suit with 40 catagories takes 9 hours to execute without docker, to speed up the execution and run it in parallel, we have chosen docker, but the high cpu utilization is the challenge for us. How to restrict container in docker-compose mode to restrict the cpu utilization ?

Comment: take a look here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources, you can specify CPU and mem limits

Comment: Tried this.Got below warning while executing and still cpu went  to 100% and test cases failed.

 WARNING: Some services (Module1,Module2....Module40) use the
'deploy' key, which will be ignored. Compose does not support 'deploy' configuration - use `docker stack deploy` to depl
oy to a swarm.

Comment: docker-compose version 3 is used with docker swarm mode. we do not have setup of docker swarm manager and worker on the host..

Comment: Use the v2 commands: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#cpu-and-other-resources

Comment: Tried this, but not able to get the cpu usage bellow 100 %
If we run 6-7 services at time, cpu usage is not triggering to 100% and we are not getting timeout or unable to connect to server error while executing scripts.
need to execute all the services paralaly to reduce the time cycle of test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with docker or cgroup namespace or qouta that you are allocating for each container, problem is with underlying jvm residing inside container
This was because Java didn’t recognize that it was running in a container. 
 try using jvm memory limits arguments i.e, JAVA_OPTS and Xms XMx options, which you can specify inside CMD or ENTRYPOINTS of your selenium (testing service container).

Also do refer https://blog.docker.com/2018/04/improved-docker-container-integration-with-java-10/
try upgrading java version for respective services. this might solve your problem.

Comment: Not using Java..using specflow framework of selenium.